# Segmentation fault while doing DFS on a coloured graph

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, depth-first-search

Here is my Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
#define limt 101

//edge stores the edges for each node
//since it is defined outside main, i don't think it is the cause for
//segmentation fault

vector<int> edge[limt][limt];
int vist[limt], tgt;

//dfs call for a node numbered <i>u</i>
//and for only the edges colored <i>c</i>
int dfs(int u, int c)
{
   if (u == tgt) return 1;

   vist[u] = 1;

   for (int i = 0; i < edge[u][c].size(); ++i) {
      if (dfs(edge[u][c][i], c)) return 1;
   }

   vist[u] = 0;
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
   //n : number of nodes
   //m: number of edges
   //c: color of edge
   int n, m;
   int u, v, c;
   cin >> n >> m;
   for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      cin >> u >> v >> c;
      edge[u][c].push_back(v);
      edge[v][c].push_back(u);
   }
   //q: number of queries/test-cases
   int q, x, y;
   cin >> q;
   while (q--) {
      cin >> x >> y;
      memset(vist, 0, sizeof(vist));
      int ans = 0;
      vist[x] = 1;
      tgt = y;

      //program crashes for second test-case after reaching here

      //i - the color of edge
      //j - all the edges from x of color i
      for (int i = 0; i < limt; ++i) {
         for (int j = 0; j < edge[x][i].size(); ++j) {
             ans += dfs(edge[x][i][j], i);
         }
      }
      vist[x] = 0;
      cout << ans << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The input i am giving is:

```
4 5
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 3 1
2 3 3
2 4 3
3
1 2
3 4
1 4
```

Here *q* is the number of test cases, the first case runs fine and gives the output *2* but on the second case program crashes with segmentation fault. I don't know what is the bug in it. I am sure i am not causing any overflow as the declarations are outside *main()*.

Comment: Well, did you step through each line of code in a debugger?

Comment: Probably debugging your program by stepping through line by line should be a rather good way to find the problem, rather than just asking here.

Comment: I used cout statements at different places, and found out that it crashes just before the starting of i-loop for the colors.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have provided the input for which the program is crashing. And from the input it is clear that the input is well withing the bounds.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have done that sir, and only after failing to find my error, i turned up here seeking some help. Why would i otherwise waste your time.

Comment: @MattMcNabb No sir, the dfs function works fine. It crashes for the second input inside the while loop, just before starting of the for loop. I have edited and marked the crash point now.

Comment: I would like to question why you have an array of vectors.  If you are using vectors why not just declare edge as a 3d vector?

Comment: That is some pretty messy code.

Comment: @NathanOliver That would be neater. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, the `dfs` function causes infinite recursion.

The first call is `dfs(u=2, c=1);` which calls `dfs(u=1, c=1);` which calls `dfs(u=2, c=1);` and so on ad nauseum.

If you run your code in a debugger you should be able to see what happened by outputting the stack trace at the point of the segmentation fault.

Here is a picture of the graph generated by your data (where the colours are 1=red, 2=green, 3=blue):

[image: Graph]

Your loop inside `main()` starts at `3` and follows Red to find `2`, then calls `dfs(2, red);` . (This was already a bit strange as you could have just called `dfs(3, red)` to get the same result).  But then the `dfs` function just follows the first Red edge it finds so it ends up shuttling back and forth between `2` and `1`.

To avoid this case you will need to add a way for `dfs` to know not to revisit a node it already visited. In fact you keep track of `vist` already but do not check it in the `dfs` function.

I think that just adding `if ( vist[u] ) return 0;` to the start of that function will fix this problem for this graph. However I think you should reset all of `vist` to `0` *for each colour*, not just for each testcase. For example in this graph if there were a blue edge from `2` to `4` but not from `3` to `4`, the search would never find it because `2` was already marked visited during the red search.

Comment: Got my mistake, thank you! I will definitely use a debugger properly before asking things like these here ..

Comment: Just a sligth modification: The first call is to dfs(u = 2, c = 1) and then to dfs(u = 1, c = 2) and son on.. My mistake was that i wasn't backtracking on visiting an already visited node.

Comment: Yes, i completely missed that case. I have to reset vist before every call to the dfs function.

Comment: @0x0101 you didn't mention what you are trying to count;  currently you're counting how many edges out of the start node lead to the dest node. (I mention this in case you were trying to count the total number of routes)

Comment: I was trying to count the number of paths that lead to the target node from source node with the path consisting of only a single colored edges. For example: In the graph you mentioned above. From node 3 to node 1 the answer is 1, that is, only one such path exists, the red colored path. This is a problem from a past contest:  (http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/505/b)

Comment: In that case you will miss a lot of paths because of `if (dfs(edge[u][c][i], c)) return 1;`  ; if multple edges have paths then you never search the other edges. Also I think some paths may be missed due to `vist` being set for an older path through that node.

Comment: After resetting `vist` before every dfs call i got it accepted on the judge. I didn't quite get the reason behind missing any paths. I am first starting from every edge starting from source node and then returning back if i have found the target node. I think the cause of confusion is my above comment. Actually i need to count the number of colors for which there is a same-colored path from source to target. So even if i am missing other paths but my work is done because that particular color is accounted in my answer now. I hope i am clearer now. Pardon my confusing language please.